# Default scan order in SCAN and LOOK disk scheduling algorithms

Tags: operating-systems, scheduling

I've been learning various disk scheduling algorithms in Operating systems. I wanted to know if there was any default scan order in SCAN, C-SCAN, LOOK and C-LOOK algorithms, like towards higher cylinders or lower cylinders ? Or are they OS-specific ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific order. In SCAN, C-SCAN, LOOK and C-LOOK we have to start moving towards the closest cylinders as in SSTF or you can start moving towards a direction in which there are less number of requests and then move towards the other